# Что-то не так с активити

Tags: android, изображения, kotlin, firebase

При загрузке фотки в storage в firebase происходят непонятности,При первом запуске всегда выкидывает в другое активити и не загружает фотку, но если из него перейти в нужное и еще раз попробовать загрузить фотку , то все работает.

```html
private fun changePhoto() {
        CropImage.activity()
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .setRequestedSize(600, 600)
            .start((activity as AdminActivity), this)
    }
```

```html
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode== CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK &&  data!=null)
        {
            val uri = CropImage.getActivityResult(data).uri
            val path= REF_STORAGE_ROOT.child(FOLDER_IMAGE_TELEVIZOR)
                .child(STORAGE_TEL.ID)
            path.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful)
                {
                    path.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener{
                        if(it.isSuccessful){
                            val photoUrl=it.result.toString()
                            STORAGE_TEL.urlImg=photoUrl
                            REF_DABATABSE_ROOT.child(NODE_TELEVIZORS).child(STORAGE_TEL.ID)
                                .child(CHIELD_TEL_URL_IMG).setValue(photoUrl).addOnCompleteListener { task2->
                                    if(task2.isSuccessful)
                                    {

                                    }
                                }

                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Как я понимаю, открывается новое активити, в котором мы выбираем или камеру или галерею, после чего обрезаем фотку до удобных размеров, но после всего этого должно открыться активити, которое указано в changePhoto, однако открывается другое

На всякий случай манифест.

```html
 <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.AdminActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.RegistryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Проблема в том, что ошибки никакой нет, в других проектах это работало правильно, но тут что-то пошло не так... Есть мысли? Иногда бывает, что  при загрузке фотки просто вылетает приложение без ошибки.

Вот такое пишет в выводе
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: Current Activity:false
not watching, wait.
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl: asyncReportData com.example.mtelevizor,2,1,2,0 interval=707
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl: asyncReportData com.example.mtelevizor,2,2,2,14 interval=743
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
I/chatty: uid=10169(com.example.mtelevizor) RenderThread identical 1 line
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
D/ViewRootImpl[AdminActivity]: surface should not be released
D/ViewRootImpl[CropImageActivity]: surface should not be released
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument